# Unable to edit text files with shared delimiter

Tags: batch-file, csv

I am trying to write a script that takes a  one lined text file containing the output from another script and removes the commas\spaces and replaces them with a carriage return.

Sample

```
ENTRY_1331_TFS273350_03, ENTRY_1331_TFS282928, ENTRY_1331_TFS292719,
```

Desired Output

```
ENTRY_1331_TFS273350_03
ENTRY_1331_TFS282928
ENTRY_1331_TFS292719
```

I have tried using variations of the below script (doesn't do anything)

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=, " %%a in (input.txt) do (
  echo %%a>> output.txt
  echo( >>output.txt
)
```

or (only echos the first object)

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims==, " %%A in (input.txt) do (
set string=%%A
echo !string!>>output.txt
echo( >>output.txt
)
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
(FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%A IN ("input.txt"
) DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO ECHO=%%B)>"output.txt"
```

Comment: Are you specifying USEBACKQ to allow double-quoting the source file name?  I suppose in case it includes a separator??  That's a new one for me I'll need to remember.

Comment: You are correct; for myself I would only use it when required but for code that could be copied by others the input and output files become unknowns so I've quoted them both to make it modular by replacement.